# how to NOT automatically run output when dashboard just starts?

Tags: python, plotly-dash

I have a table and few tabs, each tab shows ML result for the input stock ticker name from the table.  I also add a submit button, asking to not plot the data until I click the button, so I use button as input and move all the table data into State. It didn't works for the first time launching dashboard. the dashboard still automatically select the first cell's value in the table then start plotting.

So how to not plot the data until i click the button when first time launching the dashboard?  Thank you so much.

if I use a condition of if n_clicks>0 in callback function, I will get the below error:
Callback error updating svc-graph.figure, svc-markdown.children, svr-graph.figure, svr-markdown.children

```
html.Button(id='get_data_now',n_clicks=0,children='Submit',style={'fontsize':28})

# graph in the first tab
svc_graph = dcc.Graph(id="svc-graph", **graph_kwargs)
    
# graph in the 2nd tab
svr_graph = dcc.Graph(id="svr-graph", **graph_kwargs)



@app.callback(
    [
        Output("svc-graph", "figure"),
        Output("svc-markdown", "children"),
        Output("svr-graph", "figure"),
        Output("svr-markdown", "children"),
    ],
    [
        Input('get_data_now','n_clicks')
    ],
    [
        State("ticker-table", "active_cell"),
        State("ticker-table", "derived_virtual_data"),      
    ],
)

def change_graphs(n_clicks,ticker_cell, ticker_data):
   
        area, cell, data = "Ticker", ticker_cell, ticker_data
        if cell and cell["column"] == 0:
            ticker_name = data[cell["row"]] [area]
            (figs,markdown_text,df)=create_graphs(ticker_name)
            print('Done Creating Graphes')
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [callback in dash/plotly ignores if condition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70609800/callback-in-dash-plotly-ignores-if-condition)

Comment: Thank Bas van, yes that was what I was looking for.  Thank you , It works! I appreciate it.